# Computing a "sprint" based on the current date

Tags: sql, ssas, business-intelligence, powerpivot, dax

I'm building a PowerPivot/AS data model and I need to convert a date to the appropriate sprint.  A sprint is defined as a span of dates (i.e. Sprint N = date range from Date A to Date B).  Ideally, I can add this new value as a field in my Date hierarchy.  How can I write a DAX formula that will take a date and output the appropriate sprint?

To make things more complicated, in an ideal world different teams can have different dates for a sprint so it would be nice to take the teamId as input and use that to help compute the appropriate sprint name for a given date.  NOTE I do have the team/sprint name/sprint start & end dates available for querying

Answer (score 0):

I made a table that looks like the image below and used it with a date dimension table. 
[image: TeamSprints]

I am not sure how you could dynamically calculate the sprint based upon a parameter to indicate the team. This formula would work if you make one column per team in your date table in PowerPivot/Tabular AS.

```
Team1 Sprint=CALCULATE(  
    LASTNONBLANK(TeamSprints[SprintName] , 1 ), 
     FILTER(  
        TeamSprints, 
        TeamSprints[SprintName] = CALCULATE( 
                                     LASTNONBLANK( TeamSprints[SprintName],1 ),  
                                     FILTER( 
                                         TeamSprints, 
                                         TeamSprints[TeamID] = 1 &&  
                                         TeamSprints[StartDT] <= Date[DateKey] && TeamSprints[EndDT] >=Date[DateKey]
                                       ) 
                                  ) &&  
        TeamSprints[TeamID] = 1
   )   
)
```

I figured this out based on [Javier Guillen's blog post](http://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/approximate-match-with-multiple-criteria-in-dax-part-ii/)